# Low Stock notice for woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to let the customers know if the product stock goes below 10 on the product page. Here is how the page looks, when the product is "Simple product" and stock is less than 10.

[image]

However, for "Variable Products" i want to be able to show similar notification.

So far, this is what i have added on functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10);

function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
global $product;
if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled
if ( number_format( $product->stock,0,".","," ) < 10 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="leftstock">Only '. number_format($product->stock,0,".",",") . ' left in stock!</div>';
}
}
}
```

For variable products, i have this function:

```
function get_stock_variations_from_product(){
    global $product;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach($variations as $variation){
         $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
    }
}
```

I just wanted to put together this code to display the warning for both simple and variable products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the following code. This will add low stock notice to simple and variable products

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','get_stock_variations_from_product', 10);

function get_stock_variations_from_product(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_type() == 'simple' ){
        if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 && $product->get_stock_quantity() < 10 ){
            echo '<div class="leftstock">Only '. $product->get_stock_quantity() . ' left in stock!</div>';
        }
    }else if( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ){
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach($variations as $variation){
            if( isset( $variation['max_qty'] ) ){
                $attr_string = [];
                foreach ( $variation['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                    $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
                }
                if( $variation['max_qty'] > 0 && $variation['max_qty'] < 10 ){
                    echo '<div class="leftstock">'.implode( ', ', $attr_string ).' - Only '.$variation['max_qty'] . ' left in stock!</div>';
                }else if( $variation['max_qty'] < 1 ){
                    echo '<div class="leftstock">'.implode( ', ', $attr_string ).' - Out of stock!</div>';
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Works as it should :)

Comment: Is there a variant of this code, but not to display extra divs or text, but to only affect the already `built-in` Left in stock message of `woocommerce`?

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis Sorry, I didn't get whay you mean ? Could you please clarify your question ? Are you asking for a code without HTML content but only the message ?

Comment: @melvin Yes excactly, I just need the message

Comment: Are you referring to the message I added in the above code ? You could copy the above code and remove the HTML. Is that what you need ? Still I am confused.